# What is the `Thread` in this Java code?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
public class SleepMessages {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws InterruptedException {
        String importantInfo[] = {
            "Mares eat oats",
            "Does eat oats",
            "Little lambs eat ivy",
            "A kid will eat ivy too"
        };

        for (int i = 0;
             i < importantInfo.length;
             i++) {
            //Pause for 4 seconds
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            //Print a message
            System.out.println(importantInfo[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

In this piece of code there's no Thread creation, but does exist `Thread.sleep(4000)`. So what does this Thread represent? The main program itself? In other words, does Thread implicitly the program itself?

Comment: It represents the current thread executing the main method.

Comment: `Thread` is `Thread` class. One interesting thing about it is that the `sleep` method is class level method, but it will operate on the current thread where it is called.

Comment: @nhahtdh how does it accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `Thread.sleep()` acts on the current thread, which in your case is simply the one thread that always has to exist to run a program.

Comment: In this case yes, but theoretically it is possible that some other thread call the `main` method, so "current thread" is as accurate as it gets

Answer (score 2):

> does Thread implicitly the program itself?

No.  To quote from the [`Thread.sleep()` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29):

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease 
>   execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to 
>   the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers.

So `Thread.sleep()` sleeps the currently running thread which happens to the "main" thread which runs the `main(...)` method.

> So what does this Thread represent? The main program itself?

No.  `Thread` is the name of the class.  It depends on what `static` method you are calling about what it does.  For most of the per-thread methods however, (`sleep(...)`, `yield()`, etc.) `Thread.method()` applied to the current running thread or `Thread.currentThread()`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, [sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) is a static member function of class [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) that causes the thread that calls it to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

On every Java program, always exists one Thread at least. The first thread is called 'main'.

```
Thread.sleep(4000);
```

Call to the **current thread** at this moment and it is forced to wait 4000 milliseconds.

You have not created any thread but the Java Virtual machine has created the 'main' thread, responsible to run your program :)

Answer (score 0):

The static call to `sleep` causes the currently executing thread to sleep, in this case to simply to pause the output (as opposed to yielding to another thread or whatever)